# XMLA server-side library?

Tags: mondrian, xmla

I'm looking for a well documentated implementation of the XMLA protocole (proposed by Microsoft for OLAP engines). I'm looking for the server side implementation.

I found this JAVA library: [olap4j](http://www.olap4j.org/), it's not maintained. And it uses servelet. I couldn't reuse it. If any one knows how to use it without the servelet part, tell me.

I'm open to suggestions: java, scala, .net, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this project in Python [olapy](https://pypi.org/project/olapy/) which implements client & server sides of the xmla protocol. I'm inspired from it to build my own xmla library in Scala.